# Architecture for deep nested models in Ember JS

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have a question about Ember.js. 
I'm working on a drag and drop system for the content of a CMS and MailSystem. I have the following case: 
A layout consists of multiple blocks and blocks consist of multiple types of content like text or an image.

I have a solution now to build this with Ember but the solution results in high coupled classes, and this results in code that is not very testable.

I have searched a lot for a good answer for this question but I can't find a good answer. I included a class diagram to explain the problem a bit better.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Phb10.png

I have looked at a lot of examples, but can't find a useful pattern for this particular case.
Any suggestions on how to implement this in a clear, maintainable and testable way?

Comment: Look into the dependency inversion in order to make your code easier to test http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle

Comment: Hi, tanks for the help, but my question is more about the architecture then the testabilty of the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of research and trying and creating prototypes i came up with a solution. Thanks to PsiX for suggesting Dependency Injection i included it in my prototype. I want to share the prototype with you guys if anyone would have the same question.

[jsBin example](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/giloyegi/1/edit)